# session_start() carries over, but isLogged in function still redirects

Tags: php

I have a functions.php file with the following function in it;

```
function isLoggedIn(){
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['Username']){
        header("Location: login");
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=login" />';
        exit;
    }
}
```

The session is applied in the following function;

```
function checkLogin($mysqli,$Username,$Pass){
        $Password  = sha1($Pass);
        $Prep1 = "SELECT * FROM infWebAccounts WHERE Username='$Username' AND Password='$Password'";
        $Prep2 = "SELECT * FROM infWebAccounts WHERE Username='$Username'";
        $DataArray = $mysqli->query($Prep1);
        $UserArray = $mysqli->query($Prep2);
        $Maintenance = getWebSettings($mysqli,'Maintenance');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($DataArray) > 0){
            $DataTable = mysqli_fetch_array($DataArray);
            if ($Maintenance == 'Y' && $DataTable['Tier'] != 9 || $DataTable['Tier'] != 10){
                return '5';
            }
            if ($DataTable['Tier'] == 0) {
                return '4';
            }
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['Usernamee']   = $DataTable['Username'];
            $_SESSION['Tier']      = $DataTable['Tier'];
            return '3';
        } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($UserArray) > 0) {
            return '1';
        } else{
            return '2';
        }
    }
```

on every page, I include this file and run isLoggedIn() like so;

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'API/infMain.php';
IsLoggedIn();
?>
```

Even after logging in, I still get redirected right back to the login page. I echo'd the session username and it came back as my username however I still get redirected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set it with a typo

```
$_SESSION['Usernamee']   = $DataTable['Username'];
```

so this check never checks out :)

```
    if (!$_SESSION['Username']){
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
function isLoggedIn(){
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
    header("Location: login");
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=login" />';
    exit;
}
}
```

As the current code checks if it's defined but not set.

Comment: Attempted this, but I'm still getting redirected back to the login page... :/

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting if the user IS logged, shouldn't it be

```
if (!$_SESSION['Username']){
```

Also, including session_start(); before calling the function and inside the function will probably raise you a warning.

Comment: I do have it as !$_Session That was a simple mistake in my OP fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I was setting the session as 'Usernamee' and checking 'Username'